# Null Pointer to roll listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am having a problem in my android project. I have a list that fetches data from the database and put together this list I have 2 buttons one for a view and other to exclude, very similar to a contact list. But when the list is full and I try to scroll to the end or the start I receive nullpointerexception for the buttons in my ListAdapter class, I can not understand what is happening or how to solve. The buttons function normally when you not scroll the list. Sorry for my english.

My ListFragment

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button btNovaBiometria;
    private ListView lvBiometria;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private BancoDeDados bancoDeDados;
    private Context contexto;
    private View viewPai;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;

    public static ListFragment listFragment;

    public static final String LIST_VIEW_TAG = "LIST_VIEW_TAG";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewPai = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        ((PrincipalActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Lista de biometrias");
        contexto = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        listFragment = this;
        bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(contexto);
        database = bancoDeDados.getWritableDatabase();

        btNovaBiometria = (Button) viewPai.findViewById(R.id.bt_nova_biometria);
        btNovaBiometria.setOnClickListener(this);

        lvBiometria = (ListView) viewPai.findViewById(R.id.lv_biometria);
        ArrayList<Biometria> biometrias = buscarTodasBiometrias();

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(contexto,biometrias, listFragment);
        lvBiometria.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        return viewPai;
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view == btNovaBiometria){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("Lista de biometrias").replace(R.id.principal, new BiometriaFragment(), ListFragment.LIST_VIEW_TAG).commit();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Biometria> buscarTodasBiometrias(){
        ArrayList<Biometria> biometrias = new ArrayList<Biometria>();
        String sql = "SELECT _id, Tanque_id, qtd_total_animais, peso_liquido_total, media, data FROM Biometria; ";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Biometria biometria = new Biometria();
            biometria.set_id(cursor.getLong(0));
            biometria.setTanque_id(cursor.getInt(1));
            biometria.setAnimaisTotal(cursor.getInt(2));
            biometria.setPesoLiquidoTotal(cursor.getFloat(3));
            biometria.setMedia(cursor.getFloat(4));
            biometria.setData(cursor.getString(5));
            biometrias.add(biometria);

        }
        cursor.close();
        return biometrias;
    }


}
```

My ListViewHolder:

```
public class ListViewHolder {
    ImageButton btVisualizar;
    TextView tvItem;
    ImageButton btExcluir;
}
```

My ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context contexto;
    private ArrayList<Biometria> biometriaArrayList;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private BancoDeDados bancoDeDados;
    private ListFragment listFragment;


    public ListAdapter(Context contexto, ArrayList<Biometria> biometriaArrayList, ListFragment listFragment) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.biometriaArrayList = biometriaArrayList;
        this.listFragment=listFragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return biometriaArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Biometria getItem(int position) {
        return biometriaArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View row;

        bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(contexto);
        database = bancoDeDados.getWritableDatabase();

        final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;


        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,parent,false);
            listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
          listViewHolder.btExcluir = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.bt_excluir);
            listViewHolder.tvItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_Item);
            listViewHolder.btVisualizar = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.bt_visualizar);
        }else {
            row=convertView;
            listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Biometria biometria = biometriaArrayList.get(position);

          /**the nullpointer occurs exactly on that line to scroll the list view**/ listViewHolder.btExcluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(listFragment.getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Excluir");
                builder.setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja excluir este item?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                for (Biometria biometrias : biometriaArrayList) {
                                    if (biometrias.get_id() == biometria.get_id()) {
                                        try {
                                            listFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.principal, new ListFragment()).commit();
                                            String sql = "DELETE FROM Biometria WHERE _id='" + biometria.get_id() + "'";
                                            DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(database, sql, null);

                                        } catch (SQLException ex) {

                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Voce excluiu o item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });

        listViewHolder.btVisualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("Biometria", biometria);
                BiometriaResumoFragment fragobj= new BiometriaResumoFragment();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
                listFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("Lista de biometrias").replace(R.id.principal, fragobj).commit();


                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Voce Visualizou o item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        listViewHolder.tvItem.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position)));


        return row;
    }


}
```

Error Log:

```
03-30 16:03:00.821 21565-21565/br.com.agrtec.www.biometriamodulo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: br.com.agrtec.www.biometriamodulo, PID: 21565
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                       at br.com.agrtec.www.biometriamodulo.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:78)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:725)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:664)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5143)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3243)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3587)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3431)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
                                                                                       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Nativ
```

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten, already updated.

Comment: can you also add `listview_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never setting the `tag` of the `row`. Update your code so you have a call to `row.setTag(listViewHolder)` if `convertView == null`.

```
if(convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
          (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,parent,false);
    listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
    listViewHolder.btExcluir = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.bt_excluir);
    listViewHolder.tvItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_Item);
    listViewHolder.btVisualizar = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.bt_visualizar);

    row.setTag(listViewHolder); // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: Hey man,
This really works, I'm sorry for the silly mistake, and thank you for reviewing my code and help.

Comment: No worries we all make them. Glad I could help figure things out.